# Getting fields schema in GitHub api

Tags: github, github-pages, github-api

I am using GitHub api v, imagine repository api is my table. i want to show the repositories api as table and its column are [image]

i have to get the fields name and its types as genericaly.
or any other helper page that contains all the fields name and its type for all the api exist in v3. since i almost searched over the internet please provide valuable solution

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use the swagger model from https://apis.guru/browse-apis/ :

https://api.apis.guru/v2/specs/github.com/v3/swagger.json

If you want the repository definition using [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) & [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) :

```bash
curl "https://api.apis.guru/v2/specs/github.com/v3/swagger.json" | jq '.definitions.repo'
```